# Javascript id question

Tags: javascript

I have a beginner question. I have a shoutbox, an Ajax shoutbox.

I made a form where i can update the users depending on them being a DJ or not.

If that option is selected then a small image appears after the user's name.

Is working but I can't make it work but my problem is, that if I set it on my profile, it adds the image to everybody's name.

Here is my code:

```
var radios = document.getElementById("radios"); 
   if(radios.innerHTML == 'yes') {
   radios = "<img src='http://www.site/pic/radios.gif'>";
   }
```

My question is: How to insert the current user's id in this `if` statement?

Comment: yes, post the html... that will make it clearer...

Comment: You're going to have to clarify the question.  What is a current user's id?  Is it in the page?  In a cookie?  In the URL?  And, what do you want to do with it in the `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code sample you've included, there appears to be an error.

With this line of code:

```
var radios = document.getElementById("radios");
```

you get the DOM object that has an id="radios".  Then, you try to set that same variable to be a piece of HTML:

```
radios = "<img src='http://site/pic/radios.gif'>";
```

That won't accomplish anything other than setting a variable that you were previously using to store a DOM object to now be a string.  That line of code does not modify the DOM in any way.  Did you mean to write it this way?

```
radios.innerHTML = "<img src='http://site/pic/radios.gif'>";
```